# Is 1 / 0 = 0 according to Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

The following lemma:

```
lemma "(1::real) / 0 = 0" by simp
```

goes through because of theorem `division_ring_divide_zero`

I find this very disturbing since if I want to show that some fraction is non-zero I have to show that the numerator is non-zero AND the denominator is non-zero, which might make sense but confuses two different problems into one.

Is there a way of separating the well-definition of a fraction and its non-zeroness?

Comment: What exactly would be your expectation in such a situation?

Comment: @Javier Many be this could be some help https://www.hillelwayne.com/post/divide-by-zero/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isabelle/HOL is a logic of total functions, so there is no built-in notion of a fraction or any other function application being undefined. That is, `a / b` is defined for all `a` and `b`, and it returns their quotient except when `b` is zero. But then it still has a value.

In the library, the decision was made to complete the function in such a way that `x / 0 = 0`. This decision simplifies many proofs, since you have to deal with less side conditions. Unfortunately it also sometimes confuses people who expect something else.